# How can I mass-replace a set of # comments in Notepad++ when they're all different?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm not particularly computer literate.

I have a 'hosts' file I use to block sites on my computer.

The issue I'm having is that I found a second good hosts file online with a bunch of sites I'd like to add to my hosts list, some of which I seem to have already blocked and some I don't. I want to merge my hosts file with the one I've just found, but right now I have thousands of sites with my own comments added in, like this:

```
127.0.0.1 bypasser.us           # proxy site (added 13/11/18)
127.0.0.1 cnclub.za.net         # proxy site (added 15/11/18)
127.0.0.1 downuptime.net        # proxy site (added 16/11/18)
127.0.0.1 f.spoolls.com         # proxy site (added 17/11/18)
```

You get the idea...

In order to merge the two hosts files and remove duplicates I first need to remove the comments from my own hosts list.

Is there some way I can use notepad++ to remove the spaces\tabs after the URL and the # comments (which aren't all the same, many are quite different, it'd be a pain to have to go through and remove each similar note one by one)?

I think what I'm after is some sort of wildcard expression.  I've tried looking at other solutions on here but I find them difficult to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a step-by-step walkthrough in Notepad++ once you have the file open:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to open the "Replace" dialog box.
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to change the mode to "Regular expression".
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to select the "Find what" text area.
4. Type or paste `\s*#.*$`.
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> followed by <kbd>Del</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to ensure the "Replace with" field is empty if it isn't already.
6. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to "Replace all".

Output on NP++ v7.5.9 is (with no spaces at end of each URL):

```
127.0.0.1 bypasser.us
127.0.0.1 cnclub.za.net
127.0.0.1 downuptime.net
127.0.0.1 f.spoolls.com
```

The regex matches:

```
\s*     zero or more spaces
   #    literal # character
    .*  zero or more of any character
      $ end of line
```

and replaces it with an empty string.

Comment: You can also replace `$` with `\r?\n` in the regex to also remove the line (in both windows and linux line-ending style).

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can try the plugin [ConyEdit](https://www.conyedit.com). Choose one of these commands below to do this.

1. `cc.dac 2v`
2. `cc.gbc 2b`
3. `cc.gbc 1:#` and `cc.trim`
4. `cc.rc 1/\s*#.*$/ ''`